# error in performing edit operation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I have to perform the edit/update operation through the same page from which I am performing the insert operation.  I get `error undefined $select`.

This is my method :

```
function editCategory($catId,$datavalue)
{
    $data=array(
                'CategoryName' =>    $datavalue['CategoryName'],
                'Status'       =>    $datavalue['Status']
                );

    $this->db->update('tblcategory');
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('id',$catId)

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tblcategory');
    $this->db->where('id',$catId);

    $query=$this->db->get()->row(); 

    //$result=$query->row_array(); 
    if($query)
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Make the correct clause order  at `update` query means `where` and `set` clause should come first , should be like this :*

**Note** : make sure `$catId` and `$datavalue` are not empty pls add check for them

```
function editCategory($catId, $datavalue)
{
    $data = array(
        'CategoryName' => $datavalue['CategoryName'],
        'Status' => $datavalue['Status']
    );

    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where('id',$catId);
    $this->db->update('tblcategory');


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tblcategory');
    $this->db->where('id',$catId);
    $query=$this->db->get()->row(); 
    if($query)
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: but one more thing i want to add i.e i have to write query to get data from the database first then update query otherwise before getting data it made update with null values everytime

Comment: pls check empty `$data` if not then update after that

Answer (score 0):

to make it short, here is what i can help to you.

```
    function editCategory($catId, $datavalue)
    {
        $data = array(
            'CategoryName' => $datavalue['CategoryName'],
            'Status' => $datavalue['Status']
        );

        //$this->db->set($data); --> you don't need to set it because you already set the values above
        $this->db->where('id',$catId);
        $this->db->update('tblcategory',$data); //pass the data here to be inserted in your table

}
```